# Create multiples of 3 till 15 using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I am trying this below query using connect by but I am getting the relational error, someway it's not complete and I don't think there is any other way to do this.

here is the query

```
  select 3*level as X from dual 
     start with 1
     connect by  prior X < 15;
```

I want to get result as below :

```
3
6
9
12
..
..
45
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try as follows

```
    SELECT 3 * LEVEL mult
      FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 15;
```

Output

```
╔══════╗
║ mult ║
╠══════╣
║    3 ║
║    6 ║
║    9 ║
║   12 ║
║   15 ║
║   18 ║
║   21 ║
║   24 ║
║   27 ║
║   30 ║
║   33 ║
║   36 ║
║   39 ║
║   42 ║
║   45 ║
╚══════╝
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/611bf/1)

Answer (score 1):

Just to explain what you were seeing, for future reference:

```
select 3*level as X from dual 
start with 1
connect by  prior X < 15;

ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
Error at Line: 3 Column: 1
```

The error is actually complaining about your `start with` clause, which must have a *condition*; `1` is merely a literal value and cannot be used as a condition (it cannot evaluate to "true" or "false"). If we fix it so that it is now a condition:

```
select 3*level as X from dual 
start with 1 = 1
connect by  prior X < 15;

ORA-00904: "X": invalid identifier
Error at Line: 3 Column: 18
```

Now, the problem is that your `connect by` condition is referring to `X` which is not a column in the source data; unfortunately you are not allowed to refer to aliases defined in the `select` clause here.

Normally you would replace `X` with the actual expresion, e.g. `3*level` - but in this case this still won't work either because you can't refer to a pseudocolumn in a `prior` expression.

Instead, you might do this:

```
select 3*level as X from dual 
start with 1 = 1
connect by level < 15;
```

Obviously, `start with 1 = 1` is redundant and can be removed; and thus you have the answer proposed by user75ponic which works just fine.